# Simple Rails question

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a one-to-many association of Users<-Posts.

Some Posts are associated, others have a user_id of `nil`.

If, in ERB, I do:

```
post.user_id? post.user.email
```

I get a

```
undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
```

when iterating over Posts. Why does my initial conditional not protect against this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think your syntax makes sense.  Try:

```
post.user.email if post.user_id?
```

or

```
post.user_id? ? post.user.email : nil
```

or

```
if post.user_id?
    post.user.email
end
```

or

```
post.user.try(:email)
```

All of those should work.  Note: you should also be able to use `post.user.present?` or `!post.user.nil?` which both seem cleaner than checking the id.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to rephrase that slightly so that it makes more sense:

```
<%= post.user.email if post.user %>
```

I don't quite understand your code, as it doesn't look like a conditional from what you posted, but the above ERB statement should do the trick.

Edit: I should add that Ruby evaluates a nil object to false in a conditional statement, so there's no need to check for `user.nil?`, although that is still perfectly valid.  That allows you to make short, simple conditional statements like the one above.